# How to concatenate node=value pairs with & seprator

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to transform an xml-structure into a text string using xslt. I have a xml structure like this:

```
<index>
  <account index="0">00000000000</account>
  <customerId index="0">1112xxxxxxx</customerId>
  <authorization>1</authorization>
  <access>1</access>
  <documentGroup>1</documentGroup>
  <documentType>165200</documentType>
  <!-- Any number of child nodes -->
</index>
```

I need to transform this as post-parameters like this:

```
account=00000000000&customerId=1112xxxxxxx&authorization=1.....
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if you are not limited to XSLT 1.0, you can use extended XSLT 2.0 `xsl:value-of` and reduce all to a single template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="index">
        <xsl:value-of select="*/concat(local-name(),'=',.)" separator="&amp;"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Even in XSLT 1.0 you can reduce everything to single template, without the needing to adopt any iteration instruction:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="index/*">
        <xsl:if test="position()>1">
            <xsl:text>&amp;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(), '=', .)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is the best solution of all three and much better than the accepted answer. +1.

Comment: Thanks @Dimitre, you cheered me up.

Comment: Cool :-), +1 from me as well.

Comment: This answer came after accepting the solution from actionshrimp, but of course I will set this as the accepted solution :) Thanks to all contributors!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do what you need. You might need to watch out for entity encoding with the `&amp;` though, but `xsl:output method="text"`should take care of this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <xsl:output method="text"/>  
   <xsl:template match="index">
       <xsl:variable name="len" select="count(*)"/>
       <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>=<xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position() &lt; $len">&amp;</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
       </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will not 'escape' the strings though (i.e. convert things like spaces into %20), which might cause you issues, but will work for any number of child nodes which I think was the main problem you were facing?

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot, that worked beautifully :) The only change I did was to use local-name() instead of name() to get rid of any namespace prefixes if present.

Comment: But @_erik: But see and consider accepting the much better solution of @empo.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="index">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(), '=', .)"/>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
            <xsl:text>&amp;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```